# start activity automatically after receiving fcm notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to start a specific activity automatically after receiving fcm push notification.it works fine with on clicking but I want to start it automatically after the notification is received.Here is my code

My FirebaseMessagingService method where I am triggering the code

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
//changes for notification on 9/11/2017
//        if(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()!=null) {
       // Log.e(TAG, "Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    //}
    //showNotificationMessage(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
//        String click_action=remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
   // Intent i=new Intent(click_action);
 ////////////////////////////////////////
        if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "AllCallsData Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            Handler mHandler;
            //mHandler = new Handler() {
                handleDataMessage(json);
            //};
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

private void handleNotification(String message) {
    if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
        // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
        Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
        pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

        // play notification sound
        NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
        notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        //Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.);
        //Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        //r.play();
    }else{
        // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
    }
}

    private void handleDataMessage (JSONObject json){

        Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

        try {
            JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

            String title = data.getString("title");
            String message = data.getString("message");
            boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
            //String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
            String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");

            JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");
            OpenTokConfig.SESSION_ID = payload.getString("session_id");
            OpenTokConfig.API_KEY = payload.getString("api_key");
            OpenTokConfig.TOKEN = payload.getString("token_id");

            Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
            Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
            Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);

            //Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
            //Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
            Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);
            Intent i = new Intent(Config.CLICK_ACTION);
            showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, i);


            if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
                // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
                Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
                pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

                // play notification sound
                NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
                notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
                Common.call_recvd = true;
            } else {
                // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegistrationActivity.class);
                resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

                // check for image attachment
           /* if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
            } else {
                // image is present, show notification with image
                showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent, imageUrl);
            }*/
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


/**
 * Showing notification with text only
 */
private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
    //startActivity(intent);
}

/**
 * Showing notification with text and image
 */
private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, imageUrl);
}

}
```

MyNotification Utils class code

```
public void showNotificationMessage(final String title, final String message, final String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
    // Check for empty push message
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
        return;


    // notification icon
    final int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    mContext,
                    0,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
            );

    final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            mContext);

    final Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
            + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {

        if (imageUrl != null && imageUrl.length() > 4 && Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(imageUrl).matches()) {

            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);

            if (bitmap != null) {
                showBigNotification(bitmap, mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
            } else {
                showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
            }
        }
    } else {
        showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
        playNotificationSound();
    }
}
```

Comment: where this showNotificationMessage method calls? or defined ?

Comment: inOnMesageReceived() method the top Method showNotificationMessage  method id called which then calls the showNotificationMessage method in NotificationUtils class

Comment: you can do one thing,add specific view using *window manager*

Comment: can u please edit the code and tell me how to do it

Comment: @user8601021 vote you up i like KING KONG file :))

Comment: Hi @user8601021 Have you found a solution for this. I am also looking for the same functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using broadcast receiver,so when you get notification simply send the broadcast and on receiving broadcast you can write code related to start activity.

send broacast using this.

```
Intent intentNotification = new Intent();
intentNotification.setAction("com.from.notification");
sendBroadcast(intentNotification);
```

register your broadcast receiver using this :

```
getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter("com.from.notification"));
```

on receive broadcast :

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // do your stuff related to start activity
            }
        };
```

Comment: Check it i have updated my answer and let me know if you have any doubt

Comment: maybe this is right but before trying I want to ask,I have my onReceive in another activity where I am receiving the fcm token and sending with registration form while the activity I want to open once I receive the notification is different.So do i put 2 broadcast receivers in 2 activity classes?

Comment: No,you don't need to put it into 2 class,only put into onMessageReceive() method.

Comment: sorry but it still doesnt start the activity automatically

Comment: I put ur code below the intent declaration in FireBaseMessagingService and I also tried it in NotificationUtils class.the code works as before.I can click and go to the specified activity but not automatically

Comment: only send broadcast related code is in onMessageReceive() method,and to register and receive broadcast related code is in your any activity from where in broadcast receive method you can write a code related to activity transaction;.

Comment: i have put a intent filter and that name is stored in the string CLICK_ACTION which diverts to that activity on click.Regarding that broadcast receiver code i will try once again tomorrow sorry I have to leave now.wil let u know

Comment: can you send full code about that with class name??

Comment: This is wrong.  Runtime-registered receivers only work while the app is running.  Not to mention the memory leak from that non-static inner class (which, based on `getActivity()`, is on a `Fragment`).

Answer (score 0):

> automatically start an activity after receiving FCM notification in Kotlin.

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
    val notification = remoteMessage.notification
    if (notification != null) {
        val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Comment: [This won't work on Android 10 or later](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts).

Answer (score -3):

When you receive notification,

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(notificationIntent);
```

But you have to manage what to do when app is in background, foreground or killed state.

Comment: i don't think his problem be start an activity

Comment: @Mr.AF 2 he want to launch activity automatically when notification receive, that i understood

Comment: when I click on the notification the specific activity I have mentioned in intent filter click action <action android:name="TARGET_NOTIFICATION" /> is opened.But I want to open it automatically.I have edited my question with the complete code of FirBaseOnMessagingService.Please check it

Comment: I am not able to find your effort to launch your class in your code.

Comment: i did try startActivity(intent) but still it doesnt start activity automatically

Comment: did you use earlier this as a intent? : Intent i = new Intent(Config.CLICK_ACTION);

Comment: public static final String CLICK_ACTION = "TARGET_NOTIFICATION"; and then in manifest  <activity android:name=".AudioCallActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                
                <action android:name="TARGET_NOTIFICATION" />
                <!-- ////////////////////////////////////// -->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: [This won't work on Android 10 or later](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts).