# Open an activity on notification receives

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM token for push notification. How can I open a specific activity while incoming call receives. For example I want to open IncomingActivity which contains "Accept" and "Decline" button. How can I open when message receives (not onclick)

I tried the following but not working

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)

    Log.i(TAG, remoteMessage.data.toString())

    val intent = Intent(this, VideoIncomingActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `incoming call receives`?

Comment: It's a video call application. What I mean is when call receives from one device to another. i.e., When notification receives

Answer (score 1):

you should use broadcast receivers in such cases. You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358835/open-activity-on-firebase-notification-received-in-foreground) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47386221/start-activity-automatically-after-receiving-fcm-notification) S.O Questions which has similar usecase as you have.

Although if you want to use your added code then you need to set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag to your intent and that should work as well.

But remember `onMessageReceived`  is called only when the app is in foreground.

Comment: Then which method I should override to open activity when the app is in background?

Comment: You can't directly open your app from background to foreground without user clicked on it

Comment: have a look here at the official documentation :- https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Comment: Please accept the answer if it did help you so that others can find it easily.

Comment: [This won't work on Android 10 or later](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts).